# How do I customize the columns in a apex:listView?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a apex:listView for my Cases:

```
<apex:ListViews type="Case">
</apex:ListViews>
```

When I display this page, I get the columns Action, Case Number, Contact Name, Subject, Status, Priority, Date/Time Opened, and Case Owner Alias.

How would I customize which columns show up and what order the columns are in?

Thanks.

Comment: I have yet to come across a situation where I needed to use this tag - is there any reason you wouldn't just use an `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="Case" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Cases">
              <apex:outputLabel value="View:"/>
              <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="cases_table"/>
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}"/>
              </apex:selectList>
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case}" var="c" rows="50" id="cases_table" >
                    <apex:column >
                        <a target="_parent" href="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.View, c.id)}">{!c.CaseNumber}</a>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Case Number</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.ContactId}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Status}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Priority}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <base target="_parent"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If you want to customise the columns, I asked a question  at the [Salesforce stackexchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245/dynamic-number-of-columns-in-a-pageblocktable) about dynamic columns

Answer (score 1):

Apex List Views, similar to standard list views, contain a picklist at the top followed by an `Edit` button and a `Create New View` button. You can modify the view by clicking on the Edit button. There is no way, that I am aware of, to modify the columns programmatically. If you need more control, you could use another tag, such as `<apex:pageblocktable>`, as JCD mentioned in the question comments.

[image: List View Picklist Edit Button]

Comment: Awesome thanks. I made a page using `<apex:pageblocktable>`, how do I get the links to individual cases like in a `ListView`? Also, how do I get the drop down with different views?

Comment: The Case Number field is a link to an individual Case. The `apex:listviews` component always includes a drop down with different views. To add a new view, click the `Create New View` link.

Comment: When I use `<apex:pageblocktable>`, the case numbers aren't linked. Also, an option to 'Create New View' does not show up when using `<apex:pageblocktable>`. How do I get this option to show up? I am trying to get `<apex:pageblocktable>` to look like `apex:ListView`